# uitextview not scrollable with autoresizing font to fill it with any text length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, frame, font-size

I would like to make a not sliding UITextView with automatic resizing of character to fill the textview and see all the text regardless of it's length.

in some post say to compare the height of the content and that of the frame to determine the font size, for example:

```
if (self.textview.contentSize.height > self.textview.frame.size.height {
    int fontIncrement = 1;
    while (self.textview.contentSize.height > self.textview.frame.size.height) {
        self.textview.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE - fontIncrement];
        fontIncrement++;
    }
}
```

and these two lines to determine the size of the content:

```
CGSize maximumLabelSize = self.textview.frame.size;
CGSize expectSize = [self.textview sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
```

but i have many problems for apply this o similar solutions, for example:

1. in the first time, by printing frame and content heights on the console they are set to 128 instead of 350 (size of storyboard and simulator). If i change the text with some one on execution, nslog print the correct value 350 but is always the same for frame and content.
2. the frame and the content are the same height with any text.

what's my problem? there is a way to do this Correct?